# How to set tab stop in CoreText

Tags: objective-c, tabs, core-text, tabstop

I want to set the tab stop in CoreText. I really need the code. The example is more good. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3):

First off, have you read the [CoreText programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html)?

If so, take a look at the [CTTextTab reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTTextTabRef/Reference/reference.html) - specifically the CTTextTabCreate method. This should be more than enough to set you in the right direction. (We're not here to write your code for you.)